System identification using an ARX model with Gekko
The following is related to this question: Why doesn't the Gekko solver adapt to variations in the system?
What I still don't understand is why, sometimes, when the outside temperature rises, the inside temperature remains constant. Normally, it should also increase since beta remains constant. Here are examples of this:


In the two images, we can see that on the second day, the outside temperature increases and β remains constant, but the inside temperature decreases.
I checked my data and found that it had been taken every 2 seconds, which represents 43,200 measurements per day. However, during the system identification with the ARX model, I had set the sampling time to 300 sec.
I ran the corrected MPC code with 2 sec sampling from my previous question.
# Import library
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
from gekko import GEKKO
from numpy import array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# import data
tx = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\mpc\tx_b.csv')
tz = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\mpc\tz.csv')

data = pd.concat([tx,tz],axis=1)
data_1 = data[0:8596800]
data_2 = data[8596800:]

#%%  Initialize Model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# system identification
ts = 2
t = np.arange(0,len(data_1)*ts, ts)
u_id = data_1[['Tx_i','beta_i']]
y_id = data_1[['Tz_i']]

#meas : the time-series next step is predicted from prior measurements as in ARX

na=10; nb=10 # ARX coefficients
print('Identify model')
start = time.time()
yp,p,K = m.sysid(t,u_id,y_id,na,nb,objf=100,scale=False,diaglevel=0,pred='meas')
print('temps de prediction :'+str(time.time()-start)+'s')

#%% parametres 
K = array([[  0.93688819, -12.22410568]])
p = {'a': array([[ 1.08945931],
        [-0.00243571],
        [-0.00247112],
        [-0.00273341],
        [-0.00296342],
        [-0.00319516],
        [-0.00343794],
        [-0.00366398],
        [-0.00394255],
        [-0.06661506]]),
 'b': array([[[-0.05134201, -0.01035174],
         [ 0.00170311, -0.01551259],
         [ 0.00172715, -0.01178932],
         [ 0.00178147, -0.01051817],
         [ 0.00184694, -0.00821511],
         [ 0.00192371, -0.00570574],
         [ 0.00201409, -0.00344425],
         [ 0.00210016, -0.0014708 ],
         [ 0.00222189,  0.00021622],
         [ 0.03789636,  0.04235503]]]),
 'c': array([0.0266222])}


#%% I used the last day's external temperature data as a disturbance.
T_externel = data_2[["Tx_i"]].values

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.y = m.Array(m.CV,1)
m.u = m.Array(m.MV,2)
m.arx(p,m.y,m.u)

# rename CVs
m.T = m.y[0]

# rename MVs
m.beta = m.u[1]

# distrubance
m.d = m.u[0]

# distrubance and parametres
m.d = m.Param(T_externel[0])

m.bias = m.Param(0)
m.Tb = m.CV()
m.Equation(m.Tb==m.T+m.bias)

# steady state initialization
m.options.IMODE = 1
m.solve(disp=False)

# set up MPC
m.d.value = T_externel

m.options.IMODE   = 6 # MPC
m.options.CV_TYPE = 1 # the objective is an l1-norm (region)
m.options.NODES   = 2 # Collocation nodes
m.options.SOLVER  = 3 # IPOPT
m.time = np.arange(0,len(T_externel)*2,2) # step time = 300s

# Manipulated variables
m.beta.STATUS = 1  # calculated by the optimizer
m.beta.FSTATUS = 0 # use measured value
m.beta.DCOST = 0.0 # Delta cost penalty for MV movement
m.beta.UPPER = 1.0 # Upper bound
m.beta.LOWER = 0.0 # Lower bound
m.beta.MV_STEP_HOR = 1
m.beta.value = 0

# Controlled variables
m.Tb.STATUS = 1        # drive to set point
m.Tb.FSTATUS = 0       # receive measurement
m.Tb.SPHI = 17.5         # set point high level
m.Tb.SPLO = 16.5         # set point low level
m.Tb.WSPHI = 100       # set point high priority
m.Tb.WSPLO = 100       # set point low priority

T_MEAS = 20
m.Tb.value = T_MEAS
m.bias.value = T_MEAS - m.T.value[0]

m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.solve(disp=False)

if m.options.APPSTATUS == 1:
   # Retrieve new values
   beta  = m.beta.NEWVAL
   for i in range(43200):
       print(i)
else:
   # Solution failed
   beta  = 0.0

# Plot the results
plt.figure(figsize=(8,3.5))
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,m.Tb.value,'r-',label=r'$T_{int}$')
plt.plot([0,m.time[-1]],[m.Tb.SPHI,m.Tb.SPHI],'k--',label='Upper Bound')
plt.plot([0,m.time[-1]],[m.Tb.SPLO,m.Tb.SPLO],'k--',label='Lower Bound')
plt.legend(loc=1); plt.grid()
plt.ylabel('Tin (°C)')
plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,m.d.value,'g:',label=r'$T_{ext}$')
plt.ylabel('Tex (°C)')
plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.step(m.time,m.beta.value,'b--',label=r'$\beta$')
plt.ylabel('optimal control')
plt.xlabel('Time (sec)')
plt.legend(loc=1); plt.grid()
plt.savefig('results7.png',dpi=300)
plt.show()

For the external temperature over one day, I took one day's worth of data (data_2) and concatenated it with itself to create a profile for two consecutive days.

I haven't solved the problem yet.

Thanks for posting the answer. As a reminder, the StackOverflow questions should be in this section and any answers (even self-answered) are below. I've taken your question from the prior discussion in the comments and included your content in an answer. I can't run the code that you provided because it relies on local files. In the future, please include those self-contained in the code so that the solution can be verified. Also, could you let us know if the sampling interval consistency between identification and controller resolved the issue?

There is a small error where m.d is redefined and the connection is broken with the m.arx() model. Here is a correction:
# distrubance and parametres
#m.d = m.Param(T_externel[0])
m.d.value = T_externel[0]

There is also a dynamics issue. The response to beta (and likely external temperature) is very slow as shown in the step response here:

This could be from using a different sampling time interval for the SysID (System Identification) and the controller. This is especially the case if you used a short time interval for system identification and use a longer time interval for the MPC application. Because it is a discrete ARX model, the dynamics will take longer for the inputs to affect the outputs.
Response with Additional Information
Thanks for confirming that the identification was performed with 2 second data and the MPC application with 300 second time intervals. This is the source of one of the issues. One method is to use 2 sec for both (as you have shown) or else use 300 sec for both. I recommend going to 300 sec intervals for both because of the slow dynamics and need to calculate over a long time horizon. There is a way to reduce the system identification data to 300 second intervals with a rolling average and sampling every 150 data points with davg.iloc[::150]. Here are the first 500 points of the identification.

# Import library
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
from gekko import GEKKO
from numpy import array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# import data
tx = pd.read_csv('tx_b.csv')
tz = pd.read_csv('tz.csv')
data = pd.concat([tx,tz],axis=1)

# reduce from 2 sec to 5 min intervals
# calculate rolling average
davg = data.rolling(window=150).mean()
# sample every 150 cycles (2 sec to 5 min)
dnew = davg.iloc[::150]
dnew.dropna(inplace=True)

slice = int(len(dnew)*0.99)
data_1 = dnew.iloc[:slice].copy() # 99% for training
data_2 = dnew.iloc[slice:].copy() # 1% for testing

#%%  Initialize Model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# system identification
ts = 300
t = np.arange(0,len(data_1)*ts, ts)
u_id = data_1[['Tx_i','beta_i']]
y_id = data_1[['Tz_i']]

#meas : the time-series next step is predicted from prior measurements as in ARX

na=10; nb=10 # ARX coefficients
print('Identify model')
start = time.time()
yp,p,K = m.sysid(t,u_id,y_id,na,nb,objf=100,scale=False,diaglevel=0,pred='meas')
print('temps de prediction :'+str(time.time()-start)+'s')

# new parameters
print(f'Parameters: {p}')

# new gains
print(f'Gains: {K}')

# Plot the results
nview = 500
plt.figure(figsize=(8,3.5))
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(t[0:nview],data_1[['Tz_i']].iloc[0:nview],'r-',label=r'$T_{meas}$')
plt.plot(t[0:nview],yp[0:nview],'b--',label=r'$T_{pred}$')
plt.legend(loc=1); plt.grid()
plt.ylabel('Tin (°C)')
plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot(t[0:nview],data_1['Tx_i'].iloc[0:nview],'g:',label=r'$T_{ext}$')
plt.ylabel('Tex (°C)')
plt.legend(loc=1); plt.grid()
plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.step(t[0:nview],data_1['beta_i'].iloc[0:nview],'b--',label=r'$\beta$')
plt.ylabel('optimal control')
plt.xlabel('Time (sec)')
plt.legend(loc=1); plt.grid()
plt.savefig('results_id.png',dpi=300)
plt.show()

The new gains look good:
Gains: [[  0.97529892 -14.28674666]]

The new parameters are:
Parameters:
{'a': array([[ 0.65059382],
       [-0.03027903],
       [ 0.06080624],
       [-0.02233488],
       [ 0.06877417],
       [ 0.37139369],
       [-0.22535397],
       [-0.01737772],
       [-0.03430238],
       [ 0.02420281]]),
 'b': array([[[ 3.71568256e-01, -8.09407185e+00],
        [-7.62375332e-02,  4.97505860e+00],
        [-1.34657379e-01, -1.56110911e+00],
        [ 7.32255512e-02,  1.89452386e+00],
        [-2.50583697e-02, -1.68565102e+00],
        [-2.06554465e-01,  2.03970469e+00],
        [ 1.50625153e-01,  8.79190526e-01],
        [-9.20974935e-03, -1.34505749e-01],
        [ 1.58409954e-03, -6.32745151e-01],
        [ 4.79076587e-03,  1.21199721e-01]]]),
 'c': array([2.08698176])}

Here is a step response with T_externel.

# Import library
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
from gekko import GEKKO
from numpy import array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#%% parameters
p = {'a': array([[ 0.65059382],
       [-0.03027903],
       [ 0.06080624],
       [-0.02233488],
       [ 0.06877417],
       [ 0.37139369],
       [-0.22535397],
       [-0.01737772],
       [-0.03430238],
       [ 0.02420281]]),
     'b': array([[[ 3.71568256e-01, -8.09407185e+00],
        [-7.62375332e-02,  4.97505860e+00],
        [-1.34657379e-01, -1.56110911e+00],
        [ 7.32255512e-02,  1.89452386e+00],
        [-2.50583697e-02, -1.68565102e+00],
        [-2.06554465e-01,  2.03970469e+00],
        [ 1.50625153e-01,  8.79190526e-01],
        [-9.20974935e-03, -1.34505749e-01],
        [ 1.58409954e-03, -6.32745151e-01],
        [ 4.79076587e-03,  1.21199721e-01]]]),
     'c': array([2.08698176])}

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.y = m.Array(m.CV,1)
m.u = m.Array(m.MV,2)
m.arx(p,m.y,m.u)

# rename CVs
m.T = m.y[0]

# rename MVs
m.beta = m.u[1]

# distrubance
m.d = m.u[0]

# distrubance and parametres
m.d.value = 0

m.bias = m.Param(0)
m.Tb = m.CV()
m.Equation(m.Tb==m.T+m.bias)

# steady state initialization
m.options.IMODE = 1
m.solve(disp=False)

# set up MPC
n = 120 # 10 hours at 5 min sampling rate
T_externel = np.zeros(n)
T_externel[10:] = 15

m.d.value = T_externel

m.options.IMODE   = 6 # MPC
m.options.CV_TYPE = 1 # the objective is an l1-norm (region)
m.options.NODES   = 2 # Collocation nodes
m.options.SOLVER  = 3 # IPOPT
m.time = np.arange(0,len(T_externel)*300,300) # step time = 300s

# Manipulated variables
m.beta.STATUS = 0  # calculated by the optimizer
m.beta.FSTATUS = 0 # use measured value
m.beta.DCOST = 0.0 # Delta cost penalty for MV movement
m.beta.UPPER = 1.0 # Upper bound
m.beta.LOWER = 0.0 # Lower bound
m.beta.MV_STEP_HOR = 1
m.beta.value = 0

# Controlled variables
m.Tb.STATUS = 1        # drive to set point
m.Tb.FSTATUS = 0       # receive measurement
m.Tb.SPHI = 17.5         # set point high level
m.Tb.SPLO = 16.5         # set point low level
m.Tb.WSPHI = 100       # set point high priority
m.Tb.WSPLO = 100       # set point low priority

T_MEAS = 20
m.Tb.value = T_MEAS
m.bias.value = T_MEAS - m.T.value[0]

m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.solve(disp=True)

if m.options.APPSTATUS == 1:
   # Retrieve new values
   beta  = m.beta.NEWVAL
else:
   # Solution failed
   beta  = 0.0

# Plot the results
plt.figure(figsize=(8,3.5))
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,m.Tb.value,'r-',label=r'$T_{int}$')
plt.legend(loc=1); plt.grid()
plt.ylabel('Tin (°C)')
plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,m.d.value,'g:',label=r'$T_{ext}$')
plt.ylabel('Tex (°C)')
plt.legend(loc=1); plt.grid()
plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.step(m.time,m.beta.value,'b--',label=r'$\beta$')
plt.ylabel('optimal control')
plt.xlabel('Time (sec)')
plt.legend(loc=1); plt.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('results_step.png',dpi=300)
plt.show()

Here is the final controller with a sample sinusoidal profile for the external temperature.

# Import library
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
from gekko import GEKKO
from numpy import array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

total_minutes_in_day = 24 * 60
interval = 5  # minutes
num_points = total_minutes_in_day // interval
time_points = np.linspace(0, total_minutes_in_day, num_points)
# Générer les points de temps
T_externel = 8.5 + 11.5 * np.sin((2 * np.pi / total_minutes_in_day) * time_points - (np.pi / 2))

#%% parameters
p = {'a': array([[ 0.65059382],
       [-0.03027903],
       [ 0.06080624],
       [-0.02233488],
       [ 0.06877417],
       [ 0.37139369],
       [-0.22535397],
       [-0.01737772],
       [-0.03430238],
       [ 0.02420281]]),
     'b': array([[[ 3.71568256e-01, -8.09407185e+00],
        [-7.62375332e-02,  4.97505860e+00],
        [-1.34657379e-01, -1.56110911e+00],
        [ 7.32255512e-02,  1.89452386e+00],
        [-2.50583697e-02, -1.68565102e+00],
        [-2.06554465e-01,  2.03970469e+00],
        [ 1.50625153e-01,  8.79190526e-01],
        [-9.20974935e-03, -1.34505749e-01],
        [ 1.58409954e-03, -6.32745151e-01],
        [ 4.79076587e-03,  1.21199721e-01]]]),
     'c': array([2.08698176])}

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.y = m.Array(m.CV,1)
m.u = m.Array(m.MV,2)
m.arx(p,m.y,m.u)

# rename CVs
m.T = m.y[0]

# rename MVs
m.beta = m.u[1]

# distrubance
m.d = m.u[0]

# distrubance and parametres
m.d.value = 0

m.bias = m.Param(0)
m.Tb = m.CV()
m.Equation(m.Tb==m.T+m.bias)

# steady state initialization
m.options.IMODE = 1
m.solve(disp=False)

m.d.value = T_externel

m.options.IMODE   = 6 # MPC
m.options.CV_TYPE = 1 # the objective is an l1-norm (region)
m.options.NODES   = 2 # Collocation nodes
m.options.SOLVER  = 3 # IPOPT
m.time = time_points # step time = 300s

# Manipulated variables
m.beta.STATUS = 1  # calculated by the optimizer
m.beta.FSTATUS = 0 # use measured value
m.beta.DCOST = 1e-4 # Delta cost penalty for MV movement
m.beta.UPPER = 1.0 # Upper bound
m.beta.LOWER = 0.0 # Lower bound
m.beta.MV_STEP_HOR = 1
m.beta.value = 0

# Controlled variables
m.Tb.STATUS = 1        # drive to set point
m.Tb.FSTATUS = 0       # receive measurement
m.Tb.SPHI = 19         # set point high level
m.Tb.SPLO = 17         # set point low level
m.Tb.WSPHI = 100       # set point high priority
m.Tb.WSPLO = 100       # set point low priority

T_MEAS = 20
m.Tb.value = T_MEAS
m.bias.value = T_MEAS - m.T.value[0]

m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.solve(disp=True)

if m.options.APPSTATUS == 1:
   # Retrieve new values
   beta  = m.beta.NEWVAL
else:
   # Solution failed
   beta  = 0.0

# Plot the results
plt.figure(figsize=(8,3.5))
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,m.Tb.value,'r-',label=r'$T_{int}$')
plt.plot([0,m.time[-1]],[m.Tb.SPHI,m.Tb.SPHI],'k--',label='Upper Bound')
plt.plot([0,m.time[-1]],[m.Tb.SPLO,m.Tb.SPLO],'k--',label='Lower Bound')
plt.legend(loc=1); plt.grid()
plt.ylabel('Tin (°C)')
plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,m.d.value,'g:',label=r'$T_{ext}$')
plt.ylabel('Tex (°C)')
plt.legend(loc=1); plt.grid()
plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.step(m.time,m.beta.value,'b--',label=r'$\beta$')
plt.ylabel('optimal control')
plt.xlabel('Time (sec)')
plt.legend(loc=1); plt.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('results_mpc.png',dpi=300)
plt.show()


@ John I really appreciate your help and your answers. However, we can see that the internal temperature is outside the defined range. My question is: what can we do to improve the results obtained?

That is the best that the controller can do unless you put a lower weight on the lower target to allow it to pre-cool before the hot part of the day. Try setting m.Tb.WSPLO = 20 to see how it changes the solution.

I tested several values, but the temperature still exceeds during the hot part of the day

It looks like it may be a constraint on the power of the cooling system. You may also want to adjust the bias with your initial temperature.
